# Как проверить настройку ssh2 и отключение логина по паролю?

Tags: linux, безопасность, ssh, rsa, key

Провел ряд действий по повышению безопасности на сервере:
-установил модуль ssh2
-перевесил порт для ssh с 22 на 20111
-закрыл лишние порты, оставил только 80, 443, и 20111
-отключил логин по root
-отключил логин по паролям, сделал логин по ключам.

Какие есть способы убедиться, что это работает?
Пока знаю лишь два способа - просканировать порты nmap'ом и пробовать зайти на сервер по putty

Answer (score 2):

> установил модуль ssh2

вероятно, речь о `php5-ssh2` (раньше — `libssh2-php`). этот пакет не имеет отношения к демону *sshd* — используемая им библиотека `libssh2` — пользовательского уровня (*client-side*), соответственно, его наличие/отсутствие не оказывает влияния на «безопасность сервера».

> Какие есть способы убедиться, что это работает?

1. для сканирования открытых портов есть много программ (*doscan*, *knocker*, *masscan*, *pnscan* и т.п., в том числе более специализированные), из них наиболее популярна, пожалуй, именно упомянутая *nmap*. пример для поиска открытых среди всех (65535*2) *tcp-* и *udp-портов*:

   ```
   $ sudo nmap -n -PN -sT -sU -p- ip.адрес.или.имя.сканируемой.машины
   ```
2. достоверно убедиться, что пароль не принимается, можно лишь одним способом: попробовать подключиться к серверу и получить в ответ вместо приглашения к вводу пароля примерно такой текст: *Permission denied (publickey)*, а в `/var/log/auth.log` на сервере — запись вида `Connection closed by ip.адрес.клиента [preauth]`.

   из *gnu/linux* подключаться для теста, запретив использование каких-либо ключей (и из файлов и из *ssh-agent*), можно, например, так:

   ```
   $ SSH_AUTH_SOCK= ssh -o 'preferredauthentications password' пользователь@сервер
   ```

   а если добавить ещё опцию `-v` (*verbose*), то будет выдана и подробная информация о ходе «переговоров», из которой (в данном случае) существенна строка такого вида (когда доступна аутентификация только по ключу):

   ```
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
   ```

   или такого (когда доступна и аутентификация по паролю):

   ```
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
   ```